# How to accurately match an image to a video frame and exit with ffmpeg

Tags: bash, video, ffmpeg

*In Bash*,
I am trying to match an image to a frame in ffmpeg. I also want to exit the ffmpeg process when the match is found. Here is a (simplified version) of the code currently:

```
ffmpeg --hide_banner -ss 0 -to 60 \
-i "video.mp4" -i "image.jpg" -filter_complex \
"blend=difference, blackframe" -f null - </dev/null 2>log.txt &
pid=$!
trap "kill $pid 2>/dev/null" EXIT
while kill -0 $pid 2>/dev/null; do
     # (grep command to monitor log file)
     # if grep finds blackframe match, return blackframe time
done
```

To my understanding, if the video actually contains a blackframe I will get a false-positive. How can I effectively mitigate this?

While this is unnecessary to answer the question, I would like to exit the ffmpeg process without having to use grep to constantly monitor the log file, instead using pure ffmpeg

Edit: I say this because while I understand the blend filter is computing the difference, I am getting a false positive on a blackframe in my video and I don't know why.

Edit: A possible solution to this issue is to not use blackframe at all, but psnr ([Peak Signal to Noise Ratio](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#psnr)) but normal usage is by comparing two videos frame by frame, and I don't know how to effectively use it with an image as input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -t 60 -copyts -i video.mp4 -i image.jpg -filter_complex "[0]extractplanes=y[v];[1]extractplanes=y[i];[v][i]blend=difference,blackframe=0,metadata=select:key=lavfi.blackframe.pblack:value=100:function=equal,trim=duration=0.0001,metadata=print:file=-" -an -v 0 -vsync 0 -f null -
```

If a match is found, it will print to stdout a line of the form,

```
frame:179  pts:2316800 pts_time:6.03333
lavfi.blackframe.pblack=100
```

else no lines will be printed. It will exit after the first match, if found, or till whole input is processed.

Since blackframe only looks at luma, I use extractplanes both to speed up blend and also avoid any unexpected format conversions `blend` may request.

blackframe threshold is set to 0, so all frames have the blackframe value metadata tagged. False positives are not possible since blend computes the *difference*. The difference between a black input frame and the reference frame is equal to the reference frame, unless the reference is a black frame, in which case, it is not a false positive.

The first metadata filter only passes through frames with blackframe value of 100. The trim filter stops a 2nd frame from passing through (except if your video's fps is greater than 10000). The 2nd metadata filter prints the selected frame's metadata.

Comment: This is great, but I tried to use it and I couldn't get anything printed to stdout. With a video with a matching frame at `00:00:01`, it takes `14` seconds and quits without anything printed.

Comment: How is the image generated? Can you share this video and image?

Comment: The image is extracted from the video, and my original solution works in this case. The target video is Matroska. Unfortunately I cannot share the _exact_ files, but here is the download link to a video and an image from a youtube video: https://send.firefox.com/download/acd9d5c57837894b/#-dO2Nv-IAq_ReNY5fgJ7Lw This should behave the same way.

Comment: Change `value=100:function=equal` to `value=99:function=greater`. And if you're going to be working with MKVs and AVIs..etc, then add `settb=1/10000` before blackframe filter.

Comment: When extracting JPGs, compress lightly. i.e. `-q:v 1 -qmin 1 -qmax 1` else the JPEG encoding can introduce enough distortion that prevents exact matches, A bigger problem is most of the frame remains static and only subtle changes occur between frames.

Comment: Thanks, this works, and settb greatly speeds up the process. Sorry to ask, but why exactly does the timebase have to be set to 1/10000 for MKV/AVI files? Is this safe/advised to use with MP4 files as well?

Comment: MKV has a fixed tb of 1/1000 and so my trim duration does not take effect. AVIs contain no timestamps, and ffmpeg will set tb to 1/fps. No harm in always setting it.

Comment: Ok last question, (sorry again) is it possible to change this command to run in reverse (eg -ss value larger than -to). I can do it currently by using the `reverse` filter but am wondering if there is a better way. Thanks!

Comment: That's not possible. Do you want to find the last match?